# Configurable products not shown in search

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, search

I am in the process of grouping my products after colors in Magento. However, the configurable "parent" product is not showing when searching on the website.

Both the parent and child products are enabled for the page view, and the child products are set to not individually visible.

Why cant I find the parents in search?

Comment: Have you done re-index?

Comment: Are all child products enabled and saleable - i.e. have inventory (if enabled). Is the parent product enabled and set to be visible. Have you associated all the child products to the parent? Are all products associated with the correct website.

Comment: Yes, yes and yes. Everything else but the search works perfectly. The parents show correctly up in the category listings and I can add the corresponding child products to cart.